# How can I do a 201 redirect in Grails?

Tags: grails, redirect

For a more RESTful controller, an action that *creates* an entity should really return a 201 status code with the location header set, not a 30x status code. I would think that there would be a `status` parameter on the `redirect` call, but there isn't.

So, how can I do a "201 redirect" with Grails?

Answer (score 1):

A grails redirect by nature is an HTTP 302 status. If you want to return a specific status you can use `render(status: 201, ...)`.

Comment: Is there an "easy" way to put the URL of the newly created object into the `location` header using `render`? By passing in an action, for example? It isn't _just_ the status I'm looking for, it's the `location` header to be set as well.

Comment: `response.setHeader('Location', url)`

Comment: For that matter, you could use `response.setStatus(201)` as well.

Comment: I don't want to tie my controllers directly to a particular URL pattern, I want the routing engine to handle that mapping (which is what `redirect` does). Also, setting the request status prior to calling `redirect(...)` doesn't work either, since the redirect overrides that.

Comment: I think grails redirects are set to status 302 by default, not 301 [cf grails doc](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html)

Comment: @Euloiix, that's a completely separate question.